# not able to acesss both the files from form

Tags: javascript, html, file

```
    <form   name=”myForm” enctype=”multipart/form-data” >
    <div class="row pt-2 pl-3">

       <div class="col-md-5 pl-0 position-relative ">
            <!-- <input type="file" accept=".xlsx, .xls" class="input-file"> -->

            <div class="wrappeer">
              <div class="file-upload">
                <small> Drag & drop or browse  file to upload!</small> &nbsp;
                <input type="file" name="input-file" accept=".xlsx, .xls" id="input-file" />
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
              </div>
            </div> 

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row pt-2 pl-3">
      <div class="col-md-10 position-relative p-0">
        <!-- <input type="file" accept=".xlsx, .xls" class="input-file-2"> -->

        <div class="wrappeer-2">
          <div class="file-upload-2">
            <small> Drag & drop or browse  file to upload!</small> &nbsp;
            <input type="file" name="input-file" accept=".xlsx, .xls" id="input-file-2" />
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
          </div>
        </div> 

      </div>

  </div>

  <div class="pt-5 text-left pb-4">
    <button type="submit" class="button--light btn-next">SUBMIT</button> 
  </div>
  </form>
```

and here is my upload.js
I tried to print the length of the files and it's just of length one so acessing second file does not seem to be working  .

```
const form = document.querySelector('form')
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
 const formData = new FormData()
  console.log(document.querySelector('[type=file]').files);

  debugger
  const file = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files[0];
  console.log(document.querySelector('[type=file]').files[1]);



)
```

We need to read both the files and send them as formData.

Comment: why not you are using action="/upload.js"

Comment: i have this script at the end of the body .<script type="text/javascript" src="upload.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Issue is your selector:

```
document.querySelector // just returns one node
```

While in your case you need

```
document.querySelectorAll(node)// It will get you a collection of nodes
```

#### [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> The Document method `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.
>
> If you need a list of all elements matching the specified selectors, you should use `querySelectorAll()` instead.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData();
  const fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[type=file]');
  console.log(fileInputs.length);
  fileInputs.forEach(input => console.log(input.files))

})
```

```html
<form name=”myForm” enctype=”multipart/form-data”>
  <div class="row pt-2 pl-3">

    <div class="col-md-5 pl-0 position-relative ">
      <!-- <input type="file" accept=".xlsx, .xls" class="input-file"> -->

      <div class="wrappeer">
        <div class="file-upload">
          <small> Drag & drop or browse  file to upload!</small> &nbsp;
          <input type="file" name="input-file" accept=".xlsx, .xls" id="input-file" />
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row pt-2 pl-3">
    <div class="col-md-10 position-relative p-0">
      <!-- <input type="file" accept=".xlsx, .xls" class="input-file-2"> -->

      <div class="wrappeer-2">
        <div class="file-upload-2">
          <small> Drag & drop or browse  file to upload!</small> &nbsp;
          <input type="file" name="input-file" accept=".xlsx, .xls" id="input-file-2" />
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="pt-5 text-left pb-4">
    <button type="submit" class="button--light btn-next">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @horrible_nerd just added a snippet take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your issue correctly, then you should attache change event on your file input and use it to get the files values, document.querySelector will only return DOM object, and attache the event on all file input.

check my example.

```js
const file =document.querySelector('[type=file]');
// file varaibale is DOM tag and have not .file attribute.
console.log(file);

// to read the information of the file you need to triger file reader on upload event for example.
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // use the 1st file from the list
    f = files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
           console.log(theFile)
          //console.log( e.target.result );
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsText(f);
  }

  document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
test <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload">
<div id="html"></div>
```